# React.js - Simulating a click with Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have this React.js app that is a simple Cart app. https://codesandbox.io/s/znvk4p70xl

The problem is I am trying to unit test the state of the application using Jest and Enzyme but it does not seem to work. Here is my `Todo.test.js` unit test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Todo from '../components/Todo';

import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('Test it', async () => {
  // Render a checkbox with label in the document
  const cart = [
    { name: 'Green', cost: 4 },
    { name: 'Red', cost: 8 },
    { name: 'Blue', cost: 14 }
  ];

  const wrapper = mount(<Todo cart={cart} />);
  const firstInput = wrapper.find('.name');
  firstInput.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Pink' } });

  const firstCost = wrapper.find('.cost');
  firstCost.simulate('change', { target: { value: 200 } });

  const submitButton = wrapper.find('.addtocart');
  submitButton.simulate('click');

  wrapper.update();

  expect(wrapper.state('price')).toBe(26);

  console.log(wrapper.state());
  console.log(wrapper.props().cart);

});
```

When I run the test, the cart still says the same thing when the item `Pink` should have been added.

How can this be when I have simulated a button click on the `addToCart` method?

```
 PASS  src/__tests__/todo.test.js
  ● Console
    console.log src/__tests__/todo.test.js:32      { price: 26 }    
console.log src/__tests__/todo.test.js:33      [ { name: 'Green', cost: 4 },        { name: 'Red', cost: 8 },        { name: 'Blue', cost: 14 } ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to simulate a click on an element with class `addtocart`. However, you don't have an element with class `addtocart`. Your add button has an element ID of `submit`.

Change this:

`const submitButton = wrapper.find('.addtocart');`

To this:

`const submitButton = wrapper.find('#submit');`

Comment: Sorry, my code on codesandbox is out of date. I did that anyway and nonetheless -- the same error persists.

Answer (score 6):

Enzyme's `simulate` is looking for an `onChange` event on your Todo component, and it's not finding one.  You don't have `onChange` specified as a prop, so it would make sense that it's not triggering.  Wire up the `onChange` prop to your component if this is the way you want to test it.  From the docs:

> Even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event,
>   .simulate() will in fact target the component's prop based on the
>   event you give it. For example, .simulate('click') will actually get
>   the onClick prop and call it.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your `Todo` code:

```
<input id="itemname" name="name" ref={this.nameRef} className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Add item to List" />
```

and

```
<input name="cost" id="itemcost" ref={this.costRef} className="form-control" size="5" type="text" placeholder="Cost" />
```

I don't think `wrapper.find('.cost')` will work. I suggest you do `wrapper.find('#cost')`