# Simulate button click with Jest & Enzyme

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to simulate a click with jest & enzyme and I'm new to react's testing libraries.
My component is using Material UI.

Here's the part of my code I want to test:

```
                    <div>
                        <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
                            All steps completed - you're finished
                        </Typography>
                        <Button onClick={handleNext} className={classes.button}>
                            Next
                        </Button>
                    </div>
```

In this part, I want to test the button click 
Here's what I've done so far:

```
 let wrapper;
    const handleNext = jest.fn();
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(<ModelStepper handleNext={handleNext}/>)
    })
  it("handleNext increment", () => {
        const btn = wrapper.find(Button).at(1)
        expect(handleNext).toBeCalledTimes(0);
        btn.simulate("click");
        expect(handleNext).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    })
```

For some reason I'm not getting it to be clicked, I've already console logged the text of the button and it's the correct button I want to click.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is it possible for you to try [react testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro)? Their event firing is much more similar to what you have in a browser, and you wouldn't be testing implementation details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js - Simulating a click with Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224227/react-js-simulating-a-click-with-enzyme)

Comment: @JoshWilson I've took a look at the post you shared, and it didn't really help, because I can't really find out what the reason for the button not to be called, even though it found the button, and I didn't receive any error by clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation, but my button was within a form.
For this situation what works is:

```
wrapper.find('button').simulate('submit');
```

It will fire the event and evaluate changes.

Comment: I was looking around for 2 hours, and nowhere I could find why my test fails. Your answer solved it, as my button was inside a form.  I couldn't find this info in Enzyme documentation either. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line: `const btn = wrapper.find(Button).at(1)` to `const btn = wrapper.find(Button).at(0)`.

Indexing always starts at 0.